# Javascript: onrefresh or onreload?

Tags: javascript

I want an event handler that fires when the user hits reload. Is onrefresh or onreload the correct handler to add to ? Also, will this even fire before or after onunload? Are there an browser inconsistencies? Thanks.

Comment: Try this.

`const isReload = isReload = sessionStorage.getItem("loaded") ? true : false;

if (!isReload) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("loaded", true);
}`

Now you just need to check the `isReloaded` boolean to determine whether the current page was either a first load (a `false` value) or a reload (a `true` value).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there are events called onrefresh or onreload. You can know when the page is unloading, but knowing why (i.e. where the user is going next) is outside JavaScript's security sandbox. The only way to know whether the page has been reloaded is to know where the user was on the last page request, which is also outside the scope of JavaScript. You can sometimes get that via `document.referrer`, but it relies on the browser's security settings to permit access to that information.

Comment: as far as I can tell:
works
IE 8
Safari 4
doesn't work
FF 3
Chrome 2

all tested on win7

Answer (score 4):

The WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload event handler property contains the code executed when the beforeunload is sent. This event fires when a window is about to unload its resources.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
}
```

This will show a confirm dialog to the user with the message you returned in your function. It will give the user a leave this page or cancel option.

There is no way around the confirm as it could be used for malicious reasons.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: A little explanation about the code would improve your answer drastically.

Answer (score 2):

If you combine setting a cookie with a for the specific page, with a check for the onload event, you can simulate the nonexistent event you seek. You might adjust the cookie expiration so that a reload is counted only if the initial onload was a certain time interval ago.

Answer (score 0):

There are no onreload or onrefresh events that I'm aware of.  Certainly from javascript running in a browser this make little sense.  The existing window and all its contents are effectively discarded.  Hence you either need to use onunload of the existing context or the load event of the new context that is created as result of reload.

Comment: I know it's been a decade, but a suitable scenario is to stop the refresh to instead click on a refresh button on a form that securely (= no queries) passes settings information to the page for when it restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe artlung may have indeed found a way, actually... his version, however, relies on cookies, and those can be cut off from use in numerous ways; the solution, then, is to use a server-side language of your choice to save the timestamp of when the page is `unload`ed via JavaScript (still a vulnerability, yes, but why not throw another idea out there, huh?) and then testing it again upon every page load; if you detect a difference of less than a few seconds, the user probably just reloaded your page. : )

Answer (score 0):

could use a session.  easier than a cookie and don't have to worry about expiration or database.  That would cover you for any page except the first one.  I don't think the session superglobal is available til the second page.  If that's a problem, you could start a session and reload the page immediately if there is no active session.

Answer (score 0):

its onunload
because when you hit refresh the browser "unloads" then loads again