# Backbone.js and jquery mobile clear hash and reset app on window refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

Is there a way in the router to reset the url to the default page regardless of the current page the user is on if they refresh the browser?

http://appname.com/index.html

user navigates to http://appname.com/index.html#/somepage and refreshes the app stays on #/somepage I want it to go back to the start page on refresh not refresh the hash page.

Comment: And you want to execute this behavior only when the User _refreshes_?... check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738546/javascript-onrefresh-or-onreload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a bit hackish, but it works for me.

In your backbone router's initialize function, place this as the first line:

```
initialize: function(){
    window.location.hash = '';   // Remove the hash on any new page request.
    ... 
},
```

That will remove the hash from the URL and your router should route correctly.